# Clarification needed on how Node/Express processes HTTP requests concurrently and how to prevent timeouts

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I read this article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nodejs-eventloop-tutorial/ that explains how Node works. The highlight of the article is that **asynchronous tasks are processed after synchronous tasks have finished**

This got me thinking can node requests start to timeout when server is receiving large number of requests?

For example:

```
 app.post('/createUser', (req, res) => {
        // synchronous tasks like validating user information
        const name = req.body.name
        if (name===null) {
           return res.send("INVALID_NAME")
        }

        // asynchronous task of saving to SQLite db
        db.exec("*Insert into table SQL Statement*", (err,data) => {
              return res.send("SUCCESS")
        })
  })
```

In the above example: since `(err,data) => {return res.send("SUCCESS")})` is sitting in callback queue and its processing can be delayed by new incoming requests because priority is given to callstack & synchronous code.

Can requests start to timeout in the above code because before item is taken from call queue, a new request would be processing data in call stack?  What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes it can timeout but the limit for it is extremely high. With zero effort Express can easily handle around 2000 requests per second. With a small bit of optimisation (eg. caching common responses) 10000 requests per second is not an issue. You'll likely run out of RAM before you actually hit HTTP timeout (and Express is fairly lean on RAM usage, where Java typically use 1GB Express typically use 30MB)

Comment: @slebetman how can you make this piece of code less prone to being timed out given you cannot cache the result of a new insert into db?

Comment: @slebetman also how do you make it less prone to running out of ram